# JQuery With Select Options and CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I am setting two select options and customizing these options with CSS and JQuery. The issue that is happening is when selecting the options, you need to 'click' on the upper left corner of the select option, and then the options dont show gracefully, they slide out from the middle of the select box. Is there a method to ensure that anywhere you click on the select option, the drop down will populate and is there a method to ensure the drop down appears from the bottom of the select box, as opposed to coming horizontally out of the select?

Here is my Jquery code:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.extend({
    customStyle : function(options) {
       if(!$.browser.msie || ($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version>6)){
          return this.each(function() {
            var currentSelected = $(this).find(':selected');
            $(this)
                .after('<span class="customStyleSelectBox"><span   class="customStyleSelectBoxInner">' +
               currentSelected.text() +
               '</span></span>')
                .css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    opacity: 0,
                    fontSize: $(this).next().css('font-size')
                });
            var selectBoxSpan = $(this).next();
            var selectBoxWidth = parseInt($(this).width()) - 
                                 parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-left')) -
                                 parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-right'));          
            var selectBoxSpanInner = selectBoxSpan.find(':first-child');
            selectBoxSpan.css({display:'inline-block'});
            selectBoxSpanInner.css({width:selectBoxWidth, display:'inline-block'});

            var selectBoxHeight = parseInt(selectBoxSpan.height()) +  
                                  parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css  ('padding-top')) +  
                                  parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-bottom'));
            $(this).height(selectBoxHeight).change(function(){
                selectBoxSpanInner
                    .text($(this).find(':selected').text())
                    .parent().addClass('changed');
            });
          });
       }
     }
  });
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
   $('select').customStyle();
});
```

Here is my CSS:

```
span.customStyleSelectBox 
{
width:224px; 
font-size:14px;
font-family:Tahoma; 
background:url(../images/dropdown.png) no-repeat; 
color:#838383; 
padding:5px 7px; 
border:0px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 15px 15px; 
}
span.customStyleSelectBox.changed 
{ 
background-color: #FFFFFF; 
}
.customStyleSelectBoxInner 
{ 
}
```

Here is a link to my test page....

http://mdcolley.somee.com/map.asp

Thank You

Comment: You can simplify `!$.browser.msie || ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version>6)` to `!$.browser.msie || $.browser.version>6`

Answer (score 0):

[I don't see a problem with the code you posted](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/SGZf9/)

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution but add this:

```
#facility, #stateSelect{
     height:100%;
}
```

and remove height inline styles related to the two select boxes.